# Errno 24 Too many open files while multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, lambda, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a following piece of code wherein I am fetching objects from S3 bucket and adding them to a process. There are total 300 objects in the bucket.

```
parent_connections = []
processes = []
for key in s3.get_matching_s3_keys(bucket_name, prefix, ".json"):
    util.log(f"Found record with key {key} in bucket {bucket_name}")
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(duplex=False)
    parent_connections.append(parent_conn)
    process = Process(target=check_data, args=[bucket_name, key, obj_id, s3, child_conn])
    processes.append(process)

for process in processes:
    process.start()
    process.join()

for conn in parent_connections:
    output.append(conn.recv()[0])
    conn.close()
```

When executing the code, I get the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "[Errno 24] Too many open files",   
"errorType": "OSError",   
"stackTrace": [
    " File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 62, in Pipe   return Pipe(duplex)",
" File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 517, in Pipe   fd1, fd2 = os.pipe()"   ]
```

I am not sure on how to fix this? Can somebody please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating 300 processes is too many. Use a `multiprocessing.Pool` with a limited number of proceses instead, and submit your work to the pool.

Comment: @dano I don't think I can use multiprocessing.Pool in AWS Lambda because it does not support that. Is there any other way to achieve this except Pool?

Comment: You can manually create a pool using a static number of `Process` objects, and use a `multiprocessing.Queue` to distribute work to them.

Comment: Due to the Lambda execution environment not having /dev/shm (shared memory for processes) support, you can’t use multiprocessing.Queue or multiprocessing.Pool